# Cannot convert data-grid in wpf to csv without missing Arabic values

Tags: c#, wpf, csv, datagrid, export-to-csv

I am working on a project which gets data from a JSON API and displays it in a data-grid in-which the user can modify the values if required then export as CSV,the data contains Arabic text which after exporting CSV becomes a question marks instead of the actual Arabic text!!!

here is a code for reference:

```
        private void ExportToCSV(DataGrid dg)
        {
            dg.SelectAllCells();

            dg.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
            ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dg);

            dg.UnselectAllCells();
            String result = (string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue);

            //Save Location for the csv (not the actual Location)
            string SaveLocation = @"C:\Users\username\...\values"  + ".csv";

            //Overwriting previous values after exporting
            File.Delete(SaveLocation);
            File.AppendAllText(SaveLocation, result,Encoding.UTF8);

        }
```

I have tried using different Encoding like ASCII and Unicode but don't show the required result which is **Arabic text inside CSV without question marks** 
Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a solution to this problem

by first converting to Unicode text then replacing '\t' with ','
afterward, save it as CSV, here is the code:

```
        private void ExportToCSV(DataGrid dg)
        {
            dg.SelectAllCells();

            dg.ClipboardCopyMode = DataGridClipboardCopyMode.IncludeHeader;
            ApplicationCommands.Copy.Execute(null, dg);

            dg.UnselectAllCells();
            String result =(string)Clipboard.GetData(DataFormats.UnicodeText);
            string resultCSV = result.Replace('\t',',');
            //Save Location for the csv (not the actual Location)
            string SaveLocation = @"C:\Users\username\...\values"  + ".csv";

            //Overwriting previous values after exporting
            File.Delete(SaveLocation);
            File.AppendAllText(SaveLocation, result,Encoding.UTF8);

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.dataformats.unicodetext?view=netframework-4.8) to how get Unicode from Clipboard.

Comment: Not Arabic .txt file, I need CSV with Arabic values inside it.

Comment: is your txt file saved as Utf8?

Comment: It's saved as UTF-8 with BOM

Comment: i think your File.AppendAllText(SaveLocation, result,Encoding.UTF8); is ok, the problem is your result value getting from clipboard,check it pls

Comment: I have run a debug and yes clipboard copy is getting the question marks, specifically when I use DataFormats.CommaSeparatedValue